# Auto upload to ESP32 without USB to CP2102 chip

Tags: programming, esp32

I see a lot of info on how to auto-upload (meaning without holding/pressing down any button). The ESP32 dev does this using the below circuit:

[image]

However, in my case, I do not have a USB to TTL IC. I currently have two buttons (RST and PROG), in order to program my ESP32.

[image]

I also program my SMD ESP32 version using the ESP32 Dev board, but connecting the RX (ESP32 Dev) to TX (ESP32 SMD) and TX (ESP32 Dev) to RX (ESP32 SMD) and then ground the two together. Currently, this works but holding down buttons to flash the ESP32 SMD is becoming annoying, is there a way I can auto-upload like they do in the first picture?

Comment: you don't have to hold the buttons. hold io 0, click reset, release io 0. the esp stays in bootloader. initiate upload

Comment: Buy yourself the official Espressif ESP-PROG :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same situation. If your board has accessible pins on the reset and download boot strapping nets, you could rig up a Raspberry Pi / Bus Pirate / Favorite SBC/Micro with open-drain outputs to pull these pins down at the right times.

But the solution that worked a lot better for me was to implement [Over-the-Air Updates (OTA)](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/ota.html) as early as possible in the development process. It takes a little extra work, but then you don't need the UART at all for programming (after the first initial load of course).

Unrelated: why are you crossing RX and TX? Are you sure that's what you're doing? When you piggy-back an external ESP32 onto a dev board, RX and TX don't cross (that is, DevBoard.ESP32.TX <-> OffBoard.ESP32.TX). Maybe you meant from the perspective of the CP2102 (true: CP2102.RX <-> ESP32.TX).

Comment: Can you add a circuit? If possible for the wiring of the first paragraph, I only have the esp32 dev module to programme

Comment: @JoeyB I'm not sure it's possible _only_ using the dev board. The issue is that the dev board's own ESP32 must be held in reset so it doesn't conflict with your ESP32's UART. I assume this is what you're doing, Therefore you can't piggy-back the auto-download pulldown from the dev board. You'd have to pull the reset externally, either from a separate MCU/SBC or (as you're doing now) a button.

Comment: Oh I'm currently using a jumper between EN and GND on my esp32 dev board.

Comment: @JoeyB Yep, exactly, and that also pulls down the CP2102's "auto download" line (from DTR/RTS) rendering the auto logic useless. It's the same net. Hence the need for a button or an external MCU...

Comment: If you're willing to destroy your dev board, you could solve it by cutting traces.

Comment: Argh I see now. Can you provide a link on how to use another MCU, maybe an arduino nano can work?

Comment: @JoeyB I don't have a link, but all you need is an open-drain output connected to the reset and DL (IO0/IO2) nets. Then you can script a command to pull these down before connecting to the ROM bootloader. Arduino would work but you'd need a way to trigger it. With an rPi you could just have an ssh command in your script to toggle the GPIOs. (I know rPi's are hard to come by thes days...) all in all, OTA is really the way to go!

Comment: So your comment about cutting traces isn't really accurate. Which isn't a good way to describe stuff. All one once to do is desolder the esp32 module from the dev board and then solder wires to the IO0 and enable pin on the esp32 exposed pads and obviously connect TX and rx and GND and 3.3V. And quo Ollie you have a auto rest programmer. I originally thought the cp2102 IC had to be on main MCU I made but in reality I realized this can be on a programmer pcb instead so you not mass producing it.

Comment: So no complicated favorite MCU or Bus pirate stuff or Raspberry pi. The answer was in front me the whole time. No need to reinvent the wheel. Just use what I already have.... KISS (KEEP IT SIMPLE STUPID) NOTE to self hahahahaha

Comment: @JoeyB I fail to see how _removing_ the ESP32 is less destructive than cutting a trace. Sure, it can be resoldered, but so too can a cut trace be patched. I'm glad you got it working but I don't think I "described stuff in a not good / inaccurate way."

Comment: Cutting a trace is a lot harder to repair than desoldering the MCU since the copper tracks are like 0.2mm wide. Whereas soldering the ESP32 MCU is way easier since the pads are still intact. Well from my point of view and I also did cut the trace at first just so you know. You should try both methods yourself and let me know which is easier, :). Hence I find "described stuff in a not good/inaccurate way." very accurate. And the traces are way to close and the solder mask makes it even harder to know which tracks you are cutting, however I digress